# PECL solr package issue

Tags: php, solr, nginx, pecl

In solr PECL php package,to the solrQuery class we can add parameters using solrparam::set methods as name value pair.So Inorder to build a query we can use this SolrParams class.

I am just trying to figure out what are the use cases of all the methods in solrquery object.
like

> ```
>       ***"SolrQuery::addFacetDateField — Maps to facet.date
>       SolrQuery::addFacetDateOther — Adds another facet.date.other parameter
>       SolrQuery::addFacetField — Adds another field to the facet
>       SolrQuery::addFacetQuery — Adds a facet query
>       SolrQuery::addField — Specifies which fields to return in the result
>       SolrQuery::addFilterQuery — Specifies a filter query
>        SolrQuery::addHighlightField — Maps to hl.fl"***
> ```

....etc.

We can simply use the solrparam to add parameters to the query, then what is the use of these.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These methods were added to ease the use of Solr Functions, Unfortunately the current documentation misses a lot of use cases, that I'm currently working on.

It's much easier and more consistent to use methods for query functionalities like date facet without going into the Solr Documentation each time to pull parameter names. It's also less error prone.

For the time being, if you wish to learn more about these functionalities, you can check the Solr Wiki http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.date.other

The SolrParams is the ancestor of SolrQuery, SolrQuery has much more features than the bare bones(SolrParams). In the documentation its passed for SolrClient::query() as the query method accepts argument of type SolrParams (which means SolrParams any of its descendents).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about those methods. You can use the API in both ways without any penalty. Using SolrQuery methods makes your code more explicit so it's better for readability I presume.